# Converting an int to uint8_t array HEX value

Tags: c, arrays, hex, bit-shift

I'd like to take an int, and convert it into uint8_t array of hex numbers? The int is at maximum 8 bytes long in HEX after conversion. I was able to use a method that converts an int (19604) into a uint8_t array like this:

```
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-04-0C-09-04
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-4C-94
```

The algorithm I used was this:

```
void convert_file_size_to_hex(long int size)
{
    size_t wr_len = 12;
    long int decimalNumber, quotient;
    int i=wr_len, temp;

    decimalNumber = size;
    quotient = decimalNumber;
    uint8_t hexNum[wr_len];
    memset(hexNum, 0, sizeof(hexNum));

    while(quotient != 0) {
        temp = quotient % 16;
        hexNum[--i] = temp;
        quotient /= 16;
}
```

How can I go about doing this? Should I use a different algorithm or should I try to bit shift the result? I'm kinda new to bit shifting in C so some help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char hexBuffer[100]={0};
    int n=19604;
    int i;

    memcpy((char*)hexBuffer,(char*)&n,sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        printf("%02X ",hexBuffer[i]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Use just a simple statement to convert int to byte buffer

```
memcpy((char*)hexBuffer,(char*)&n,sizeof(int));
```

You can use 8 instead of 4 while print the loop

Comment: +1 I thought this was the simplest and straight forward way to do this without using any algorithms and custom datatypes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since `n % 16` has a range of 0..15, inclusive, you are making an array of single hex digits from your number. If you would like to make an array of bytes, use `256` instead:

```
while(quotient != 0) {
    temp = quotient % 256;
    hexNum[--i] = temp;
    quotient /= 256;
}
```

You can rewrite the same with bit shifts and bit masking:

```
while(quotient != 0) {
    temp = quotient & 0xFF;
    hexNum[--i] = temp;
    quotient >>= 8;
}
```

To know how many bytes you need regardless of the system, use `sizeof(int)`:

```
size_t wr_len = sizeof(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a union for this

```c
union int_to_bytes {
        int i;
        uint8_t b[sizeof(int)];
};

union int_to_bytes test = { .i = 19604 };

int i = sizeof(test.b); // Little-Endian
while (i--)
        printf("%hhx ", test.b[i]); // 0 0 4c 94

putchar('\n');
```